# Scroll to Focused Field Cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

### My Issue

I am currently in the process of writing an application for iOS using Cordova. I have a page with a form on it like so:

[image: Form Example]

When the user taps on a field, the keyboard appears as expected on iOS. However, to prevent my app from moving off the screen, I have enabled the following setting:

```
// Prevent the keyboard from pushing up the webview
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
```

Unfortunately, this prevents a few things that are causing me issues:

1. When a field is focused, the screen does not scroll to that field so sometimes, the field appears behind the keyboard.
2. Even if I did have a solution to the above, for the elements that are at the bottom of the screen, I will not be able to scroll down far enough to bring them into view above the keyboard.

### My Question(s)

#### Solution 1

Is there any way, in Cordova, to auto scroll to the focused field **without** moving the whole app off the screen?

If it is possible, then how can I handle fields that are close to the bottom and cannot be scrolled up any further into view?

Obviously, the first point can be achieved using JavaScript/jQuery and some clever logic with the `keyboard_height`, `position()` and `scrollTop()`. But, this then creates the issue with the second point about the input fields behind the keyboard...

#### Solution 2

If I apply the following code, it will fix the issue highlighted above, but it will create another issue (explained below):

```
// Enable the auto scroll when the keyboard is shown
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(false);
```

Is there anyway to fix my header (the 'Edit Profile' bit), to the top of the screen to ensure that part is always visible?

Comment: Did you find the relevant solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use `https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-keyboard#keyboardshrinkview` and its `Keyboard.shrinkView` method.